# Need help with overheating st

Tags: overheating, radiator, thermostat

We have changed the radiator in the fan to the radiator and my car is still overheating. Do I need to change the thermostat or could there be another possible reason why it is overheating?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please add more details to your question? Such as the vehicle year/make/model/engine? Also, please specifically describe a little bit better what you've done (or had done) to the vehicle. It appears you've changed your radiator, but your question is very unclear. Please help us a little bit so we can help you :o)